# How to pass data to a generic angular component (dialog)

Tags: angular, angular-material

Is there a more intuitive way to accomplish what I have below?

I am trying to make a generic dialog component that the caller can customize by passing in a setupParam class.

I'm still new to the Angular world, while the below code does function as I want, it's not very intuitive to another developer that the setupParam class is needed.

Dialog HTML:

```
<div>
  <h2 mat-dialog-title>{{setupParams.title}}</h2>
  <mat-dialog-content>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </mat-dialog-content>
  <mat-dialog-actions>
    <button mat-raised mat-dialog-close [mat-dialog-close]="false">{{setupParams.button1}}</button>
    <button mat-raised [mat-dialog-close]="true">{{setupParams.button2}}</button>
  </mat-dialog-actions>
</div>
```

Dialog Typescript:

```
export class DialogGeneric {

  public setupParams: GenericDialogProperties;

  constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) {
    this.setupParams = data.dialogParams;
  }
    //public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogGeneric>, @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) {}

}
```

Calling program Typescript:

```
  myMethod(id) {
    let myDialog = this.dialog.open(MyDialog, {
      height: "400px", width: "400px",
      data: { someData: "some data", dialogParams: this.modalSetup },
  });
```

Comment: What is for you more intuitive ?

Comment: Something required when calling the dialog.  Right now they can pass nothing to it and the dialog would be empty for the most part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not using @Input Decorators in your dialog Component 
Example:

In dialog Component:

```
 import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
    @Component({
    .....
    })
    export class DialogComponent{
       @Input() data: any;
    }
```

In parent component:

```
<dialog [data]='dataObject'>
```

**dataObject** is an object that you will fill in the parent class with the text, title, images that you want to show in the Dialog

```
dataObject = {
    title: 'Title',
    text: 'Some question or any text' 
}
```

[Documentation and full example](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)